# picking a unique set from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, mathematical-optimization

I attempted to ask a more complicated of this before but I couldn't explain it well so I am trying again with a simplified use case.

I will have an array of arrays like the following

```js
var allData = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I need to select 1 element from each array so that I get a unique set like [2,4,1,3,5] easy to do in this case as each array has all values.  However this will rarely be the case.  Instead I may have

```js
var allData = [[1,2,4],[1,2],[1,2],[2,4,5],[1,2,3,5]]
```

In this case I couldn't pick 1 or 2 from the first array as that would prevent the 2nd and 3rd from having a unique combination.  So something like [4,2,1,5,3] or [4,1,2,5,3] would be the only two possible answers for this combination.

The only way I see to do this is to just go through every combination but these will get fairly large so it doesn't seem reasonable as this happens real time.  There are going to be at least 7 arrays, possibly 14 and distantly possible to have 31 so going through every combination would be fairly rough.

The 2nd part is if there is some way to "know" you have the best possible option.  Say if there was some way I would know that having a single duplicate is my best case scenario.  Even if I have to brute force it if I encounter a 1 duplication solution I would know to stop.

One easy way to get a very simple of this is to just subtract the number of possible choices from the number of elements but this is the correct answer in only the simplest of cases.  Is there some type of library or anything to help solve these types of problems?  It is a bit beyond my math abilities.

Here is something I have tried but it is too slow for larger sets and can fail.  It works sometimes for the 2nd case I presented but only on luck

```js
const allData = [[1,2,4],[1,2],[1,2],[2,4,5],[1,2,3,5]]
var selectedData = []
for (var i in allData){
  console.log("length",allData[i].length)
  var j = 0
  while(j < allData[i].length){
    console.log("chekcing",allData[i][j])
    if (selectedData.includes(allData[i][j])){
      console.log("removing item")
      allData[i].splice(j,1)
    }
    else{j++}
  }
  var uniqueIds = Object.keys(allData[i])
  console.log(uniqueIds)
  var randId = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueIds.length)
  console.log(randId)
  selectedData.push(allData[i][randId])  
  console.log("selectedData",selectedData)
}
```

Comment: asking for library is ot. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: It's a nontrivial conceptual question. Not "implement this logic into code", but "what sort of logic could possibly work here", which is reasonable

Comment: I am putting in an edit for something I have tried

Comment: That is my main issue, it is more of a fundamental concept that I am having troubles wrapping my brain around what it even means to solve this.  Which is why I mention brute force which eliminates any actual understanding of the underlying math.  Yes it works but not well.

Comment: a quantum computer might be useful here....

Comment: About the only thing I can think of is a series of fallbacks.
Pass 1 checks all items, if there are n total arrays, if I have n elements at minimum in each array it is the simplest solution, I can just go through like in my code example and it will always work.  
Pass 2 If there are n unique values across all arrays.  It is likely but not guaranteed that there is a solution.  Attempt to solve them from most to least restrictive.
Pass 3  is if neither is true.  Where I don't think there is a good way to know for sure and getting a best out of 100 attempts may be all I can get

Comment: This is a lot like a sudoku.  The row (result array) must contain a different item in each cell, the candidates for each of the row cells are given (that's the array of arrays).

Comment: I wish i were better at proving, whether this is NP-complete. It looks a lot like it, but i'd have to read up on things for a while before finding a related problem, and a reduction.

Answer (score 1):

You could count all elements and take various comparison with same indices.

```js
function x([...data]) {
    while (data.some(Array.isArray)) {
        const
            counts = data.reduce((r, a, i) => {
                if (Array.isArray(a)) a.forEach(v => (r[JSON.stringify(v)] = r[JSON.stringify(v)] || []).push(i));
                return r;
            }, {}),
            entries = Object.entries(counts),
            update = ([k, v]) => {
                if (v.length === 1) {
                    data[v[0]] = JSON.parse(k);
                    return true;
                }
            };

        if (entries.some(update)) continue;

        const grouped = entries.reduce((r, [, a]) => {
            const key = JSON.stringify(a);
            r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
            return r;
        }, {});

        Object.entries(grouped).forEach(([json, length]) => {
            const indices = JSON.parse(json);
            if (indices.length === length) {
                let j = 0;
                indices.forEach(i => data[i] = data[i][j++]);
                return;
            }
            if (length === 1) {
                const value = JSON.parse(entries.find(([_, a]) => JSON.stringify(a) === json)[0]);
                indices.forEach(i => data[i] = data[i].filter(v => v !== value));
                data[indices[0]] = value;
            }
        });
    }
    return data;
}

console.log(...x([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]));
console.log(...x([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]]));
console.log(...x([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10]]));
```

Comment: Thank you, I am taking a look at these and trying to understand what it means.  Unfortunately my javascript skills are severely lacking but it looks promising

Comment: I am trying to get this to work but the site I am working on doesn't support the ??= syntax.  I am trying to rewrite this without it but not having any luck.  I really need to get a better understanding of all the shorthand arrow notation haha

Comment: please see edit. basically this `a ??= []` is the short way of `a = a || []` with `undefined` or `null` values.

Comment: Thank you! I am learning a lot (well trying to) looking at these answers.  My knowledge is pretty basic and I tend to use all very low level type concepts.  Which is MUCH longer than a lot of the concise logic here.  Just shows me there is a ton I need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a fairly simple backtracking algorithm:

```js
function pick(bins, n = 0, res = {}) {
    if (n === bins.length) {
        return res
    }

    for (let x of bins[n]) {
        if (!res[x]) {
            res[x] = n + 1
            let found = pick(bins, n + 1, res)
            if (found)
                return found
            res[x] = 0
        }
    }
}

//

let a = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
console.log(pick(a))
```

This returns a mapping `item => bin index + 1`, which is easy to convert back to an array if needed.

This should perform relatively well for N < 10, for more/larger bins you can think of some optimizations, for example, avoid the worst case scenario by sorting bins from smallest to longest, or, depending on the nature of elements, represent bins as bitmasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation based around counting occurrences across the arrays.

It first creates a map indexed by value counting the number of inner arrays each value occurs in. It then sorts by inner array length to prioritize shorter arrays, and then iterates over each inner array, sorting by occurrence and selecting the first non-duplicate with the lowest count, or, if there are no unique values, the element with the lowest count.

```js
const
  occurrencesAcrossArrays = (arr) =>
    arr
      .reduce((a, _arr) => {
        [...new Set(_arr)].forEach(n => {
          a[n] = a[n] || 0;
          a[n] += 1;
        });
        return a;
      }, {}),
  generateCombination = (arr) => {
    const dist = occurrencesAcrossArrays(arr)
    return arr
      .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
      .reduce((a, _arr) => {
        _arr.sort((a, b) => dist[a] - dist[b]);

        let m = _arr.find(n => !a.includes(n));
        if (m !== undefined) {
          a.push(m);
        } else {
          a.push(_arr[0]);
        }

        return a;
      }, []);
  };

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]).toString());
console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]]).toString());
console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10]]).toString());
```

**Edit**

In response to your comment – The situation seems to be emerging because the values all have the same occurrence count and are sequential.

This can be solved by keeping a running count of each value in the result array, and sorting each inner array by both by this running occurrence count as well as the original distribution count.This adds complexity to the sort, but allows you to simply access the first element in the array (the element with the lowest rate of occurrence in the result with the lowest occurrence count across all arrays).

```js
const
  occurrencesAcrossArrays = (arr) =>
    arr
      .reduce((a, _arr) => {
        [...new Set(_arr)].forEach(n => {
          a[n] = a[n] || 0;
          a[n] += 1;
        });
        return a;
      }, {}),
  generateCombination = (arr) => {
    const dist = occurrencesAcrossArrays(arr)
    return arr
      .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
      .reduce((acc, _arr) => {
        _arr.sort((a, b) => (acc.occurrences[a] || 0) - (acc.occurrences[b] || 0) || dist[a] - dist[b]);

        let m = _arr[0]

        acc.occurrences[m] = acc.occurrences[m] || 0;
        acc.occurrences[m] += 1;

        acc.result.push(m);

        return acc;
      }, { result: [], occurrences: {} })
      .result; // return the .result property of the accumulator
  };


console.log(generateCombination([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]).toString());
// 2,3,4,5,6,2,3

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]).toString());
// 1,2,3,4,5

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]]).toString());
// 1,2,4,5,3

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10]]).toString());
//1,2,4,5,3,9,6,10,7,8

console.log(generateCombination([[1], [2, 3,], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]).toString());
// 1,2,4,6,7
```

***A note on .reduce()***

If you're having trouble getting your head around `.reduce()` you can rewrite all the instances of it in this example using `.forEach()` and declaring accumulator variables outside of the loop. (This will not always be the case, depending on how you manipulate the accumulator value within a reduce() call).

Example below:

```js
const occurrencesAcrossArrays = (arr) => {
  const occurrences = {};

  arr.forEach(_arr => {
    [...new Set(_arr)].forEach(n => {
      occurrences[n] = occurrences[n] || 0;
      occurrences[n] += 1;
    });
  });

  return occurrences;
};

const generateCombination = (arr) => {
  const dist = occurrencesAcrossArrays(arr);
  const result = [];
  const occurrences = {};

  arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  
  arr.forEach(_arr => {
    _arr.sort((a, b) => (occurrences[a] || 0) - (occurrences[b] || 0) || dist[a] - dist[b]);

    let m = _arr[0]

    occurrences[m] = occurrences[m] || 0;
    occurrences[m] += 1;

    result.push(m);
  });

  return result;
};


console.log(generateCombination([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]).toString());
// 2,3,4,5,6,2,3

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]).toString());
// 1,2,3,4,5

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]]).toString());
// 1,2,4,5,3

console.log(generateCombination([[1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10], [6, 7, 8, 10]]).toString());
//1,2,4,5,3,9,6,10,7,8

console.log(generateCombination([[1], [2, 3,], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]).toString());
// 1,2,4,6,7
```

Comment: I am trying to run this but the syntax a[n] ??= 0 doesn't work where I am testing.
Is this the same as
if (a[n] === undefined){a[n] = 0}

Comment: yes, your replacement is correct. I've edited to remove the logical nullish assignment operator

Comment: I am close to getting this to work on my site but I am trying to change 1 thing.  It seems to keep picking the same value if there are not enough values so in this set for example 

console.log(generateCombination([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]).toString());

it returns 2,3,4,5,6,2,2.  I am trying to read up on the reduce of arrays.  Any pointers of where to look to change this?

Comment: Edited with possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem using a MILP-model. Here is one implementation in MiniZinc (data has been extended to seven days):

```
int: Days = 7;
int: Items = 5;

set of int: DAY = 1..Days;
set of int: ITEM = 1..Items;

array[DAY, ITEM] of 0..1: A = % whether item k is allowed on day i 
    [| 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
     | 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 
     | 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 
     | 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 
     | 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 
     | 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 
     | 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 |];

array[DAY, ITEM] of var 0..1: x; % 1 if item selected k on day i, otherwise 0
array[DAY, DAY, ITEM] of var 0..1: w; % 1 if item k selected on both day i and day j, otherwise 0

% exactly one item per day
constraint forall(i in DAY)
    (sum(k in ITEM)(x[i, k]) = 1);

% linking variables x and w
constraint forall(i, j in DAY, k in ITEM where i < j)
    (w[i, j, k] <= x[i, k] /\ w[i, j, k] <= x[j, k] /\ w[i, j, k] >= x[i, k] + x[j, k] - 1);
     
% try to minimize duplicates and if there are duplicates put them as far apart as possible
var int: obj = sum(i, j in DAY, k in ITEM where i < j)(((Days - (j - i))^2)*w[i, j, k]);

solve minimize obj;

output 
["obj="] ++ [show(obj)] ++
["\nitem="] ++ [show([sum(k in ITEM)(k*x[i, k]) | i in DAY])];
```

Running gives:

```
obj=8
item=[2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The following package looks promising for a JavaScript implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-lp-solver

Comment: I will take a look at this along with some real data.  I think that if I am getting a large number of results I can stick with something random but if I get a smaller set in return I will need to be more intelligent like this.  Thank you